# How do I add WMS to OpenLayers 5.3.0?

Tags: openlayers, wms

I am trying to integrate a WMS overlay onto my default OpenLayers map. Using just the `ol.source.OSM({})` layer the map renders fine, but when I add the WMS layer to the `layers: []` array it just gives me a blank map. I am using the following code but it isn't working, what do I need to change?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>WMS Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile(
                {
                    source: new ol.source.OSM({})
                }),
            new ol.layer.ImageWMS(
                {
                    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS(
                    {
                        url: 'http://www.igeo.pt/WMS/Geologia/CGP1M'
                    })
                })
        ],
        view: new ol.View(
            {
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
                zoom: 4
            })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need to specify the WMS parameters (an object specifying at least LAYERS) see the example https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/wms-image.html

Comment: I see. How can I find out what the layers are? All I have is the WMS link.

Comment: its ol.layer.Image for ImageWMS source.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the GetCapabilities for that url http://www.igeo.pt/WMS/Geologia/CGP1M?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
There are 17 layers named 1 to 20 (3, 13 and 18 are missing) with Portuguese descriptions.  In the unlikely event of you wanting all the setup would be as below (note the layer constructor is simply `ol.layer.Image`, the Lon/Lat order, and I've made it semi-opaque so the background is still visible)

```
        new ol.layer.Tile(
            {
                source: new ol.source.OSM({})
            }),
        new ol.layer.Image(
            {
                source: new ol.source.ImageWMS(
                {
                    url: 'http://www.igeo.pt/WMS/Geologia/CGP1M',
                    params: { LAYERS: '1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,19,20'}
                }),
                opacity: 0.5
            })
    ],
    view: new ol.View(
        {
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-8.82, 37.41]),
            zoom: 4
        })
```

On a full screen map it is usually more efficient to request the WMS in tiled areas to avoid continually requesting the whole area when panning

```
        new ol.layer.Tile(
            {
                source: new ol.source.TileWMS(
                {
                    url: 'http://www.igeo.pt/WMS/Geologia/CGP1M',
                    params: { LAYERS: '1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,19,20'}
                }),
                opacity: 0.5
            })
```

Comment: This code is giving me problems. I can't omit "import {Map, View} from 'ol';" library and use ol.Map or ol.View using direct reference. Also "ol.proj.fromLonLat" isn't working maybe for the same reasons. It seems I have to directly inculde the libraries which is a pain because I end up having a multi-line "header".

Comment: It works when replacing the code in your question, which is using the full build library.  If you want to use NPM the syntax will vary depending on how you import.

Comment: I understand. I'm currently using NPM. I have been told it's more performant to use modules explicitly. I am still unable to use your "View" code even if I import fromLonLat by using "iimport { fromLonLat } from 'ol/proj';". It causes a blank map. Any idea why?

Comment: Here's an example using fromLonLat via NPM https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/xyz-esri.html
Also ImageWMS and TileWMS NPM examples
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-image.html
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-tiled.html

Comment: @Mike problem with the official OpenLayers examples are they're all writen as `import ...` etc etc. where the syntax throughout the script is different to when you work from a downloaded copy of the javascript libraries.